# $_COOKIE is storing only last inserted value

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

i am trying to insert multiple values in a cookie, but i could able to store only one value. hear is my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
$rand= "SED".rand(10000,99999);
?>
<!doctype>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<form action="result4.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="<?=$rand?>">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my result4.php

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "lastview";
$cookie_value = array($_POST['productid']);
$init = json_encode($cookie_value);
setcookie($cookie_name, $init, time() + (86400 * 30));
?>
<?php
echo count($_COOKIE["lastview"]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_COOKIE["lastview"]);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

output

```
1
["SED73204"]
```

i am trying to get this

```
5
["SED73204"]
["SED73507"]
["SED23207"]
["SED73286"]
["SED23294"]
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior? What's the actual output?

Comment: You are not reading the content of the cookie before overwriting it. Read it, make in back into an array, add a value, write it back.

Comment: how to read can you give a example

Comment: i understand that its overwriting the existing cookie value. but how to get multiple values

Comment: If you are going to do this then there are some limits / gotchas. 1) COOKIES have a limited size (4KB officially) 2) They can be messed with on the client. So, 1) Store the array in the session or database with a unique id. 2) send the unique id in the cookie. I tend to use hashes of unique id's but it isn't required.

Comment: my problem is not resolved

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, check if a value exists in the cookie already. If it does then extract that first, then add the new value.

```
$cookie_name = "lastview";

// Set the cookie value from previous (if exists) or else an empty array
$cookie_value = (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) ?     
json_decode($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) : array();

// Add the new value to the array if one exists
if (isset($_POST['productid']) && is_numeric($_POST['productid'])) {
    $cookie_value[] = $_POST['productid'];
}

// Set the cookie
setcookie($cookie_name, json_encode($cookie_value), time() + (86400 * 30));
```

You may want to replace the call to `is_numeric` here with a `preg_match` to check for more specific product ID formats. For example:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\w]{3}[\d]{5}$/', $_POST['productid'])) { ... }
```

Also, you won't be able to see any values in the `$_COOKIE` array in the same execution cycle as `setcookie()`. You will need to wait for the browser to send the cookie back on the next request before you see the populated value in the `$_COOKIE` array.

Comment: i got warning message: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in

Comment: This is the answer except OP's product  id's don't appear to be numeric

Comment: Updated the answer with a regex for your specific product id case.

Answer (score 0):

You cant direclty store an array into a cookie,

One way to do would be to serialize the data :

```
setcookie('cookie', serialize($cookie_value), time()+3600);
```

Then unserialize data:

```
$data = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie']);
```

Comment: BEWARE: The PHP `unserialize()` function is usable for remote code execution and should NEVER EVER be used for strings that have been defined by an attacker.